# Is automatic screen mirroring broken in or removed from iOS 6+?

Tags: ios, ios6, mirroring

I want to do this with my app and device:

1. Connect VGA, DVI, or HDMI monitor to appropriate 30-pin adapter cable
2. Connect adapter to iPhone4/iPad2
3. Mirror iDevice screen content on monitor screen.

This all used to "just work" on iOS 5. There's even proof of it working in a YouTube video of our demo from last year (see http://youtu.be/xjKk1EJ1yAI, to skip to the image jump to 1:40 in the video and hit play). All I did was plug in the iPad and *voila* there it was...

This now seems to "just not work." Do I have to write a whole bunch of code to make this work with every app I build or is there a setting in the Info.plist file that I should set? Should I build for iOS 5.1 to make it work again, even though the device runs iOS 6+?

I ***will*** write the code if I have to, but I'd be a lot happier if it just worked again. The "similar questions" feeature on SO was helpful in letting me know that I'm perhaps out of luck and pointing to some solutions, like Rob Terrell's [TVOutManager](http://www.touchcentric.com/blog/archives/123), but I wasn't able to find an answer to this specific question in that list.

***EDIT:** I only tried this with an iPhone 4 running iOS 6.0.1 and the VGA adapter. I haven't tried again with an iPad (also with iOS 6.0.1), and the video was using the HDMI adapter. I will try those and update accordingly (but probably not until Monday for those updates).*

Comment: The iPhone 4 never supported screen mirroring, only the A5 devices did (4S, 5, iPad 2+). You could manually output content via a second screen in your application, but you had to write code to do that. OS-level screen mirroring required capabilities in the A5 GPU.

Comment: +1 That could explain a lot of what I saw today. The source in the linked video is an iPad 2 (basic, ordered right when they went on sale in 2011) and it also has the A5 CPU. I never tried it with iPhone 4 before, so I just expected it to work. Fortunately, I have a pair of iPhone 5's on order (needed them to be factory unlocked) that should arrive next week.

Comment: Just to commend on the comment, that while it is true that iPhone 4 never supported screen mirroring, but that is a limitation placed on it by Apple.  Jailbroken iPhone 4 can enable screen mirroring with relatively ease.  So it has nothing to do with A5 GPU as suggested by the comment